# How to save intermediate outputs into images on a multi-stage pipeline?

Tags: halide

Say I have computation something like

```
Image resultA, resultB;
Func A, B, C, D, E; 
Var x, y;
A(x,y) = C(x,y) * D(x,y);
B(x,y) = C(x,y) - D(x,y);
E(x,y) = abs(A(x,y)/B(x,y));  

resultA(x,y) = sqrt(E(x,y));

resultB(x,y) =  2.f * E(x,y) + C(x,y);
```

How to define AOT schedule such that I can save `resultA` and `resultB` ?
`E(x,y)` is common to the computation of `resultA` and `resultB`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results are the same size in all dimensions, you can return a Tuple:

```
result(x, y) = Tuple(resultA, resultB);
```

If they are not the same size, they can be added to a Pipeline and the Pipeline can be compiled to a filter that returns multiple Funcs.

See:

https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/multiple_outputs.cpp